# BufferedWriter causes break

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a save function for a program I'm working on, and for some reason whenever I run it, it only gets past the first line of the try{} statement. 
My code is as appears below.

```
  public void saveGame() { 
            System.out.println("saveGame");
     try
     {
        System.out.println("try saveGame");
        BufferedWriter b = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("chardata.txt"));
        System.out.println("try saveGame2");
        String sp = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        System.out.println("try saveGame3");

        b.write("Miscellaneous char data here");

        b.close();
     }
        catch(IOException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("File Writing Error");
            }
  }
```

When I run the program, the only lines that get printed are "saveGame" and "try saveGame." There is no "File Writing Error" either, it simply doesn't do anything after the "try saveGame" line. I'm not sure if this is relevant, but I am doing this from a computer at a school, which may have restricted permissions. Any kind of explanation and/or help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Permissions would through an `Exception` so I don't think it's that.

Comment: I would temporarily catch Throwable and dump out the stack trace. There must be an exception somewhere.

Comment: `new FileWriter("chardata.txt")`  are you sure you have to pass the file name string, or you have to pass any object???

Comment: Have you tried waiting and see if there is a timeout? I'm guessing permission problems with file creation.

Answer (score 0):

I think a better way to write your file would be using `FileOutputStream` and `OutputStreamWriter`.
Additionaly, you should move your `b.close` to a finally statement because if an exception  is thrown before that `b.close` was executed, it never will be executed.

```
public void saveGame() { 
     System.out.println("saveGame");
     try
     {
        System.out.println("try saveGame");
        String path = "./chardata.txt"; //your file path
        File file = new File(path);
        FileOutputStream fsal = new FileOutputStream(file);
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fsal);
        Writer w = new BufferedWriter(osw);
        System.out.println("try saveGame2");
        String sp = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        System.out.println("try saveGame3");

        w.write("Miscellaneous char data here");

     }
        catch(IOException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("File Writing Error");
        }
        finally{
            if(w!=null)
              w.close();
        }
  }
```

Comment: I tried this code, but it wasn't working so I added in a System.out.println() between FileOutputStream and OutputStreamWriter and it did not print.

Comment: Test if you are setting right the path of your file. If that is right, the code would work (for me works perfectly)

Comment: I think it may be a problem with my computer's permissions to write to/access text files. "chardata.txt" is in the same directory as the java class.

Comment: So maybe that will be a permission problem. Try putting your file on a folder in which you have write permission (I guess you have at least one)